# Can not input anymore on MOZILLA OS phone

Tags: android, firefox

1. Import 2000 contacts from SD card with 2000+ content.vcf.
2. Set USB storage enable.
3. Copy some videos to SD card on PC side.
4. When copying videos to SD card user click setting->storage->application data
5. Phone UI freeze

Debug self:

1. adb is well
2. can not find any more useful info from top
3. get process stack use debuggerd
4. adb shell getevent is valid

Input reader thread is epool_wait status, but /dev/input/event* is valid from getevent, I can not get more useful information.

Could any bros can give me more suggestion for this issue?

Comment: "InputReader" sysTid=624
  #00  pc 00021804  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
  #01  pc 0002a27f  /system/b2g/libmozglue.so (__wrap_epoll_wait+166)
  #02  pc 011cf141  /system/b2g/libxul.so

Comment: "b2g" sysTid=204
  #00  pc 00021804  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
  #01  pc 0002a27f  /system/b2g/libmozglue.so (__wrap_epoll_wait+166)
  #02  pc 011de29d  /system/b2g/libxul.so
  #03  pc 011c3d3d  /system/b2g/libxul.so